# Find City, State, & County of User Inputted Zip Code (United States Zip codes only)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I need to find the city, state, and county of a user inputted zip code or user inputted city,/state using JavaScript.

I understand that some (very few) cities/zip codes in the United States are located in 2 or more counties.

I am using the Google Maps Geocoding API to accomplish this but I am having issues with certain zip codes.

**Works correctly for the following (and many others):**

- 90210 (City: Beverly Hills State: CA County: Los Angeles County)
- 55101 (City: Saint Paul State: MN County: Ramsey County)
- 77001 (City: Houston State: TX County: Harris County)

**Works incorrectly for the following (and many others):**

- 24501 (Lynchburg, VA) - Does not display anything
- 10001 (New York, NY) - Does not display anything

I am making 2 requests to the Google Maps Geocoding API. The first request is to find the city and state of the user's inputted zip code. The second request takes the city and state and finds the county. I plan on using my Geocoding API key for each request but it is working fine without while testing locally.

**My code is as follows:**

```js
function submit_form() {

    var city;
    var state;
    var county;

    // Get the user's input
    var zip = document.getElementById("user_input").value;

    // Make a request to the Google Maps Geocoding API
    // Find city and state of the user's zip code
    $.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+zip, function(data){

              var address_components = data.results[0].address_components;

              $.each(address_components, function(index, component){
                     var types = component.types;

                     $.each(types, function(index, type){
                            if(type == 'locality') {
                                city = component.long_name;
                            }
                            if(type == 'administrative_area_level_1') {
                                state = component.short_name;
                            }
                     });
              });

              callCounty();
    });

    // Make a request to the Google Maps Geocoding API
    // Find the county of the city and state
    function callCounty() {
        $.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+city+state, function(data){

            var address_components = data.results[0].address_components;

              $.each(address_components, function(index, component){
                     var types = component.types;

                     $.each(types, function(index, type){
                            if(type == 'administrative_area_level_2') {
                                county = component.short_name;
                                waitToCall();
                            }
                     });
              });
        });
    }

    function waitToCall() {
        document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += "<p><strong>City:</strong> " + city + " <strong>State:</strong> " + state + " <strong>County:</strong> " + county + "</p>";
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Find Your City, State, and County</h1>
<p>Enter your zip code or your city, state:</p>
<form>
<input type="text" name="user_input" id="user_input" placeholder="City, State, or Zip code" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submit_form()"/>
</form>
<div id="log"><p>Results will show here.</p></div>
```

Comment: It looks like the second call to get the address for certain city/states does not return the administrative_level_2 field, but the first call *does* get that field.  You might not need the second call at all, or you might only need the second call if the first call does not contain the county.

Answer (score 0):

This example tries to get the county out of the zip code request.  If it's not found it tries the city/state request.  I changed your inner each loops into indexOf lookups.

```js
function submit_form() {

    var city;
    var state;
    var county;

    // Get the user's input
    var zip = document.getElementById("user_input").value;

    // Make a request to the Google Maps Geocoding API
    // Find city and state of the user's zip code
    $.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+zip, function(data){

      var address_components = data.results[0].address_components;

      $.each(address_components, function(index, component){
        var types = component.types;
        if (types.indexOf('locality') > -1)
          city = component.long_name;
        else if (types.indexOf('administrative_area_level_1') > -1)
          state = component.short_name;
        else if (types.indexOf('administrative_area_level_2') > -1)
          county = component.short_name;
      });
              
      if (!county)
        callCounty();
      else
        waitToCall();
    });

    // Make a request to the Google Maps Geocoding API
    // Find the county of the city and state
    function callCounty() {
        $.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+city+state,          
          function(data){
            var address_components = data.results[0].address_components;
            $.each(address_components, function(index, component){
              var types = component.types;
              if (types.indexOf('administrative_area_level_2') > -1) 
                county = component.short_name;
            });
            if (county)
              waitToCall();
              
          });
    }

    function waitToCall() {
        document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += "<p><strong>City:</strong> " + city + " <strong>State:</strong> " + state + " <strong>County:</strong> " + county + "</p>";
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Find Your City, State, and County</h1>
<p>Enter your zip code or your city, state:</p>
<form>
<input type="text" name="user_input" id="user_input" placeholder="City, State, or Zip code" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submit_form()"/>
</form>
<div id="log"><p>Results will show here.</p></div>
```

Comment: Thank you but it still has issues for certain zip codes like my original code. Your code does work for zip code 10001 (New York, NY) but still does not work for 24501 (Lynchburg, VA) - it displays nothing like my code does. I looked into the API documentation to try and find if there was a parameter that always returned the county in the first request but it appears that it is not an option.

Comment: Interestingly, Lynchburg is not in a county because it's an [independent city](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_city_(United_States))